# Solving ODE with initial condition, one step wrong

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a step wrong while solving my IVP but I cannot find what. I will post my detailed solution in the hope someone sees where it goes awry:
The IVP: $$t^2 \frac{dy}{dt}−t=1+y+ty,y(1)=4.$$

1. I start by moving all function of y on the RHS:
   $$\displaystyle$$
   $$\displaystyle t^2\frac{dy}{dt}-y-ty=1 +t$$
   $$t^2\frac{dy}{dt}-(1+t)y=1 +t$$
2. It is not in standard form so I continue by divinding by $t^2$:
   $$\frac{dy}{dt}-\frac{(1+t)}{t^2}y=\frac{1 +t}{t^2}$$
3. With $h(t) = -\frac{(1+t)}{t^2}$ I can use integrating factor $e^{\int h(t)}$ = $e^{H(t)}$. With $H(t) = \frac{1}{t} - ln(t)$, I get :

$$e^{\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)}\frac{dy}{dt}- e^{\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)}\frac{(1+t)}{t^2}y=\frac{1 +t}{t^2}e^{\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)}$$
Which can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)} y) = \frac{1 +t}{t^2}e^{\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)}$$
$$\displaystyle e^{\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)} y = \int{ \frac{1 +t}{t^2}e^{\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)}} $$

$$\displaystyle e^{\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)} y =  -e^{\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)} + C $$
4. by multiplying with $e^-H(t)= e^{-\left(\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)\right)}$ we get:

$$ y(1) = 4 =  -1 + Ce^{-\left(\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)\right)} \\
C = 5e$$

5. The initial value condition gives that C:

$$y(1) = 4 =  -1 + Ce^{-\left(\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)\right)} \\
C = 5e$$
$$y(t) = -1 + 5 e e^{-\left(\frac{1}{t} - ln(t)\right)}  \\ 
y(t) = -1 + 5 e^{-\left(\frac{1}{t} - ln(t) - 1\right)}$$

But this appears to be wrong. Is there some step I am doing wrong?

**EDIT: fixed -1 in exponent as per the comments.**

**EDIT 2: trying to plug in in the original equation**

Simplifying we get:
$$y(t) = -1 + 5 t e^{1-\frac{1}{t}}\\
y'(t) =  5  e^{1-\frac{1}{t}} + 5t \frac{1}{t^2}e^{1-\frac{1}{t}} \\
y'(t) =  5  e^{1-\frac{1}{t}} + 5 \frac{1}{t}e^{1-\frac{1}{t}}$$

$$t^2 \frac{dy}{dt}−t=1+y+ty \\
t^2 \left(5  e^{1-\frac{1}{t}} + 5t \frac{1}{t}e^{1-\frac{1}{t}} \right) -t = 1 -1 + 5 t e^{1-\frac{1}{t}}  -t + 5 t^2 e^{1-\frac{1}{t}} $$

Seems everything is disappearing, but I still get wrong on the automatic assessment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolate the derivative on the left side
$$
t^2y'=1+t+y+yt=(1+t)(1+y).
$$
This is a separable first order DE, so that
$$
\ln(1+y)=\int\frac{dy}{1+y}=\int\frac{(1+t)dt}{t^2}=-\frac1t+\ln(t)+c
\\~\\
(1+y)=Cte^{-1/t}.
$$
Etc.

Comment: Oh that was neat!

Comment: Thank you everyone, I appreciated everyone's answer and I will vote @lutzlehmann up, since the answer was much more compact and a way to tackle the equation I did not thought about.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct note that $$e^{-1/t+\ln t}= te^{-1/t}.$$
Notr that $e^{ln z}=z$.

Answer (score 1):

Note Z Ahmed's answer; also, in the very last step, notice it is

$$5e^{-(\frac{1}{t}-\ln t-1)}.$$

Comment: Right. thank you. Yet it is not right when I plug it back in the original equation.

Comment: @Dovendyr Maybe I'm missing something but I think it should work out when you plug it in. Can you say how it's wrong? Like how much is it off by?

Comment: Ok let me edit with pluggin in... just a sec :)

Comment: Sorry it seems right. But the webwork still refuses my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

\begin{align*}
t^{2}\frac{dy}{dt} - t =1+y+ty \Leftrightarrow \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{t^{2}} + \frac{1}{t^2}y+\frac{1}{t}y+\frac{1}{t} = y(\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t})+(\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t})
\end{align*}
Which is a linear equation. Solving this equation you conclude:
\begin{equation*}
y(t) = Ce^{-\frac{1}{t}}t - 1 \hspace{1cm}, C \in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
Knowing that $y(1)=4$ you get:
\begin{equation*}
y(1) = 4 \Leftrightarrow C\frac{1}{e}-1 = 4 \Leftrightarrow C = 5e
\end{equation*}
Finally, you have:
\begin{equation*}
y(t) = 5e^{1-\frac{1}{t}}t-1 = 5e^{\frac{t-1}{t}}t-1
\end{equation*}
Which verifies the inicial equation.